# Recovery Services Vault - What does LRS vs GRS apply to in this context?

Tags: azure, azure-storage

An Azure Recovery Services Vault has a "Backup Configuration" setting to control the "storage replication type" of the vault.  There are 2 options: LRS or GRS storage.  I need some guidance on what this means in the context of a vault.

1) What exactly does the LRS/GRS setting of a recovery services vault apply too when it comes to a vault?  For example does it apply to the settings/configuration of the vault, does it apply to any backup data in the vault?

2) If the GRS setting applies to backup data within the vault does this mean that in the event of a disaster all backup data within the vault will be made available to a secondary region when a failover is triggered?

3) If point #2 above is true what is the point of recovery services vault replication?  Does this just allow a customer to failover whenever they want instead of waiting for Microsoft to initiate the failover?

Comment: What do you mean by "recovery services vault replication"? Are you talking about the "replicated items" section, as this has nothing to do with geo-redundancy, this is about replicating VMs into the vault.

Comment: A Recovery Services Vault has a "Backup Configuration" setting "Storage Replication Type" with 2 options: "Locally-redundant" and "Geo-redundant".  You can access this setting by navigating in the portal to "Recovery Services Vault" -> Pick your vault -> "Properties" -> Under the "Backup Configuration" heading press "Update"

Comment: Right, but you seem to be asking what the difference is between that and the LRS/GRS setting, they are the same thing.

Comment: I'm just trying to understand what the LRS/GRS options do in the context of a recovery services vault.  Specifically the 3 bulleted questions that I imagine would be impacted by the selection of LRS or GRS.

Answer (score 1):

Using GRS for a recovery service vault means that your data is replicated to a second region. If the primary region goes down you will still be able to restore data using this recovery service vault in the secondary region.

GRS storage failover is under the control of Microsoft, they will choose when to failover (which has not happened yet), not  you. There is a preview running for customer initiated failover for GRS storage, but this does not extend to backup vaults.